# PHP watemarking images with rest servis

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, watermark

I was searching for a while and I was not able to find solution or to figure it out by myself. I am using Codeigniter for a rest servis, and I need to watermark images on my website. I know how to watermark it and save it, but did not find a way to watermark it dynamicly when using REST.

For example when my home page loads it calls rest service for image paths, than I return image paths to browser, and this is the moment when I need to watermark images.

Comment: When your website is called you can do anything you want in the backend, no one cares, so just generate/collect the watermarked images, then display them.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! But I need my images to be nonwatermarked on my server, for other usage. Just want to watermark it dynamicly when representing.

Comment: Then do the following: When an image is requested: create a watermarked image and put it inside a temporary directory, then show the watermarked image to the user (You could also pre-generate the watermarks, then put them into a folder and just return them instead of the originals).

Comment: I was thinking about hacks like that, but I was wondering if there is some better solution, so asked question here, thanks anyway.

Comment: Those aren't "hacks". Those are examples of how you need to do it. If you want to watermark images, you simply need to generate a new image. I would suggest to do it when the image gets added. If you do it upon request, the request could (and probably would) be slow, since it needs to wait for the generation to be done.

Comment: I thought there is a way to do this on the fly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You _could_ generate the images with watermark in the back end when an image get's requested (just set up a route that looks like the image path) and simply return the binary data. That would be very insufficient though, since every call to an image would generate a new image. It would be slow and eat up your CPU and RAM in no time if you get a bunch of concurrent requests.